# Jetpack Compose Preview Render Problem with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.ext.SdkExtensions error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was able to use compose preview but after some library updates, I cannot use it anymore. How can I solve this error?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/ext/SdkExtensions   
at androidx.core.os.BuildCompat$Extensions30Impl.<clinit>(BuildCompat.java:302)   
at androidx.core.os.BuildCompat.<clinit>(BuildCompat.java:256)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.android.BoringLayoutFactory.measure(BoringLayoutFactory.kt:49)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.android.LayoutIntrinsics.getBoringMetrics(LayoutIntrinsics.kt:55)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.android.LayoutIntrinsics.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(LayoutIntrinsics.kt:82)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AndroidParagraphIntrinsics.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(AndroidParagraphIntrinsics.android.kt:64)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.MultiParagraphIntrinsics$maxIntrinsicWidth$2.invoke(MultiParagraphIntrinsics.kt:82)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.MultiParagraphIntrinsics$maxIntrinsicWidth$2.invoke(MultiParagraphIntrinsics.kt:80)   
at _layoutlib_._internal_.kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)   
at androidx.compose.ui.text.MultiParagraphIntrinsics.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(MultiParagraphIntrinsics.kt:80)   
at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextDelegate.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(TextDelegate.kt:121)   
at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextDelegate.layoutText-K40F9xA(TextDelegate.kt:200)   
at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextDelegate.layout-NN6Ew-U(TextDelegate.kt:248)   
at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextController$measurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(CoreText.kt:306)   
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:106)   
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:649)  
......
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating androidx.core:core-ktx library from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0.
After reverting back to 1.9.0 the preview is rendering again.

Looking at the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#:%7E:text=Added%20BuildCompat%20constants%20for%20SDK%20extension%20versions.%20(I6084c)) for 1.10.0, there was an update made to SdkExtensions ([Pull request](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2300437/1/core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/os/BuildCompat.java#19) ).

Comment: I confirm the issue. Reverting back to 1.9.0 fixed it...

Comment: I also confirm that solved issue for me. Downgrade to 1.9.0 and rebuild project.

Comment: This worked for me also, is there any rumor of a fix for it, and a 1.11.0 release?

Answer (score 1):

For me, as of 15/May/2023, I just upgraded my `'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0-alpha02'` to `'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0-alpha04'` and the preview error was solved.

Btw I didn't downgrade or upgrade my `'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'`, although it can be upgraded to 1.10.1, but don't do anything upgrading it.

I didn't try downgrading `'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'` to 1.9.0. I guess it suits me better, upgrading to `'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0-alpha04'`.