# Jetpack Compose fails preview if there is a Text composable in composition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My Android Studio version is `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1`
My jetpack compose related dependencies are as follows:

```
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class"
```

Everything works fine, but when I include even a single `Text` composable in the composition the Preview brakes with message `some issues were found when trying to render this preview`
So this preview does not work:

```
@Preview(showSystemUi = true, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewTest() {
    Text(text = "hello")
}
```

but putting anything else instead of `Text` works just fine.
Any ideas why this can happen?

Comment: try to update compose-bom version from 23.01.00 to `23.04.00`

Comment: Already updated, but this does not work.

Comment: What do your includes look like at the top of your compose file? Make sure that `Text` you are including is the proper package.

Comment: I am sure it is from correct package as when I run the app everything works very good. p.s. here is the package `androidx.compose.material3`

Comment: If you can upload you source code to find issue

Comment: Could it be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75937541/jetpack-compose-preview-render-problem-with-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-an/75963867#75963867

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade Android Studio to `Flamingo`. It seems `Electric Eel` and `Dolphin` have some preview-related issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to find the cause if you share the problem window of android studio.

[image]

Comment: I don't think your answer adds anything of good value to this question, this could be a comment.